# What is the difference between 's' and 'state' in section 5.2 of "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (3E)"

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, pseudocode

I am reading chapter five of this textbook and am getting stuck trying to interpret the `min-max algorithm`, please let me know if I am simply fixating on needless detail. The algorithm in question is `figure 5.3`:

```
function Minimax-Decision(state) returns an action  
    return argmax[a ∈ Actions(s)] Min-Value(Result(state, a))

function Max-Value(state) returns a utility value  
    if Terminal-Test(state) then return Utility(state)  
    v ← -∞  
    for each a in Actions(state) do  
        v ← Max(v, Min-Value(Results(s, a)))  
    return v

function Min-Value(state) returns a utility value  
    if Terminal-Test(state) then return Utility(state)  
    v ← ∞  
    for each a in Actions(state) do  
        v ← Min(v, Max-Value(Results(s, a)))  
    return v
```

My question is the difference between `'s' and 'state'`. I know that they are both states and that `'state'` which is passed to `Minimax-Decision` would be the current state. The way that `argmax` inputs `'s'` into `Actions()` while inputting `'state'` into `Result()` puzzles me however. It occurs again in both `Max-Value() and Min-Value()` where the parameter is `'state'` but `'s'` is passed to `Result()`. What is the difference, if any, between these two states?

Comment: Seems to be a typo, `s` should have been `state`.

Comment: This is covered (if you can find it - search for minimax) in the errata list for the book: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/3rd-ed/errata.html

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, this is likely a typo.